Cartoon in which little characters drink something and suddenly start bouncing
I remember seeing a cartoon back in early 2000s or late 90s. There are bunch of short guys, which on seeing some sort of danger would drink some liquid contained in a bottle.
The liquid would give them the strength to fight against their enemies and would all start bouncing.
Don't remember much, but was a famous cartoon series.

Were they bears (and drank gummiberry juice)?

Ya exactly, they were Gummi Bears.

I still have the theme song burned into my brain, much to my wife's annoyance.

You're looking for the Gummi Bears, an animated show from the 80s and early 90s. The potion that they drank which enabled them to bounce away from their enemies was called Gummiberry Juice. Here's the intro and its catchy theme song:



(If you were looking for something more Gummi-Bear-specific, let me know.)

This is the one I was looking for. Thanks for the help.
